# How to combine varchar value with null value

Tags: sql-server

I  want to combine varchar value with null value

FOR EG:

```
SELECT COL1
FROM(
SELECT 'ABC' AS COL1
UNION 
SELECT '' AS COL1) T
```

This is giving me two result 'abc' and 'null'
but I want to add 'abc' with 'null' to get one result only ie: 'abc'
like we do with number by using sum operator in main query

```
SELECT SUM(COL1)
FROM
(
SELECT 1 AS COL1
UNION
SELECT '' AS COL1
) P
```

The result will be '1'

how can I do that with varchar value

Comment: Are you looking for `CONCAT`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Comment: @shree.pat18 : It is `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL, OP should look for workarounds in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Give a `WHERE` condition

```
  SELECT COL1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 'ABC' AS COL1
        UNION 
        SELECT '' AS COL1        
    ) T
    WHERE COL1 IS NOT NULL AND COL1 <> ''
```